# How can I make quick expression that's visible to assign to const?

Tags: c++, c++17, coding-style

I want to assign some value to a const, where it used to be something like

```
const int x = animal == "cat" ? 0 : 1;
```

But now, I want to make it so that if animal == cat, assign 0, and if dog returns 1, else 2 to the const. Well, in reality, it's not that simple but say something like use equation a, in this case, equation b, and equation c in this case.

Of course, I can always do something like

```
const int x = FunctionToHandleIt();
```

But the logic is so simple. I think it's much cleaner for the code to write out the expression right there so people can look at it and know exactly what's happening right then and there instead of going through the header and definition of the function to see what's happening.

What is the better way to handle a case like this to assign something to const that's more than a few lines? But, not worth making a whole function for it?

Comment: "I want to assign some value to a const" you cannot assign to `const`. If you want to assign to it make it non const

Comment: You may want to look into the [Immediately invoked function expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately_invoked_function_expression) idiom. In C++, this can be implemented by using an immediately invoked lambda function like `const int x = [animal]() { if (animal == "cat") { return ... } else { return ... } }();` (notice the pair of `()` at the end of the line).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the help of a lambda function, there is no need to specify the definition of another function somewhere in the code.

```
const string animal = "dog";

const int x = [animal]() {
    if (animal == "cat")
        return 0;
    else if (animal == "dog")
        return 1;
    else
        return 2;
}();

cout << x << endl;
```

The variable `animal` is captured to be validated in the inner code block. The respective values are returned after that.

Comment: To match the original, you'd want to move the `()` from `x()` down in the print statement up to where you're initializing `const auto x` so that `x` is an `int`, not a lambda.

Comment: This works, but I’d recommend making it a proper free function: `int animalAsNumber(std::string_view animal);` then you can reuse that function, and you can test it.

Comment: @Ben The OP wanted something inline that would refrain from defining functions.

Comment: I know, but the OP is asking a style question, and this is a clear case of a function that should be free, even if it’s only used once. But most likely it’ll be used repeatedly.